# Where does Nitrogen get the best performance - yaws, mochiweb, or inets?

Tags: erlang, mochiweb, yaws, nitrogen, inets

The [Nitrogen project](http://nitrogenproject.com/) web page declares equal support for yaws, mochiweb, and inets, but with which of these web servers is it going to perform the best? I.e. for a large scale application with mostly dynamic content with nitrogen + a web server which combination will be able to handle the most user load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A question like this is highly dependent on the application. Any answer would have to be taken with a grain of salt and is definitely not a substitute for doing your own system tests. However, with all of that said, I believe the yaws and mochiweb are fairly similar in performance. yaws is the older project and may be more stable as a result but not neccessarily. I've almost no experience with inets so I'm not going to comment on it.

Your best bet is to run a set of benchmark tests for your app with each one and see what you get. It's so easy to switch between them in nitrogen that you can run tests with the same app and draw your own conclusions.

Comment: Agreed - for a _real_ answer benchmarking would have to be done. I was looking for a general answer and it looks like I got it. Really just trying to flush out if there was some glaring difference between them that I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I believe they are similar in performance. The major difference is that Mochiweb is faster and nimbler while Yaws handles more concurrent connections.

Inets is only for local testing however. I wouldn't bother checking it out.

Comment: The next version of the Erlang.org site (http://demo.erlang.org/) is hosted on inets. It can't be *that* bad.

Comment: Yeah but thats a demo. They will probably move to another server for launch. At least I would think so.

It's not really "bad" though. Didn't mean it like that. It's small, convenient and built in. But it's just not nearly as good as the other two.

Answer (score 1):

Mochiweb is the fastest because Bob Ippolito wrote it. :)

I have benchmarked it and My memory tell me it was much better then the rest of them. What I can remember it was stable and did not explode in error messages under heavy load. But don't trust me. Test it your self.